# Using WebAPI to create/update records which have an FK relationship to another table - do I need to create 2 separate controllers in my WebAPI?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables, a Contact table and a Department table.  The relationship is "1 Contact to many Departments".  When I am creating/updating a Contact record along with the associated Department records (on the same form), do I need to have two separate controllers in my WebAPI (one for Contact and one for Department) to handle the create/update for both entities, or will my single Contact controller handle updating both the Contact table and Department table since they're linked by way of a foreign key?

Comment: Is this more of a "Best Practice" question or a "Technically Feasible" one?  Technically you can do both in one controller while best practice is another more subjective question, though I don't believe there is anything wrong with handling both in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one controller which will be something like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostContractDepartments(Contract contract, Department[] departments)
```

Or you can have a Contract-departments specific complex model, in which you will have contract info and list of department info

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostContractDepartments(ContractDepartments contractDepartments)
```

Some people prefer this to "chatty applications".
But I think, best is to update one department at the time, one contract at the time, etc. Then you can build "clean" application.